# How to have subscription side effects of source observable trigger only when the subscriber count changes from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a source `Observable<Void>` that:

- registers some `BroadcastReceivers` when its subscribed to
- unregisters them when unsubscribed from.
- I only want subscription side effects to occur when the subscriber count increases from 0 to 1, or from 1 back to 0.
- Adding a 2nd subscriber to this observable should have no effect on the source observable (I don't want to register the `BroadcastReceivers` twice)

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **.share()** operator

```
Observable<Void> src = ...;
Observable<Void> shareable = src
    .doOnSubscribe(() -> {...})
    .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> {...})
    .share()  //<------------ or publish.refcount(1)
```

Note: There's a race condition here for additional subscribers. if you are expecting to receive an event when you subscribe initially for every subscriber, use `.replayingShare()` from https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare - this caches the latest value while still unsubscribing from the source when it has no subscribers.

Comment: you're ignoring the no-op requirement

Comment: @DaveMoten what do you mean? Going from 2 to 1 subscribers here or from 1 to 2 does nothing to the source observable

Comment: If subscription is a no-op for the second subscriber then the second subscriber should not receive any events.

Comment: @DaveMoten oh sorry, I meant that the source observable would be unaffected by the additional subscriber

Comment: Righto, can you fix the question then? Looks like `share` is it.

Comment: @DaveMoten fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Not a guaranteed solution, but *maybe* this:

```
Observable<Void> src = ...;
Observable<Void> shareable = src
    .doOnSubscribe(() -> {...})
    .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> {...})
    .publish()
    .autoConnect();
```

Then you subscribe to the `shareable` Observable. Please test first!

Comment: when you unsubscribe from this, `doOnUnsubscribe()` does NOT get called. `.autoConnect()` keeps the upstream alive once subscribed to.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do subscriber-specific things `defer` is a really useful operator:

```
Observable<Integer> source = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);

// control subscribers via this atomic boolean
AtomicBoolean subscribed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
Observable<Integer> o = Observable.defer(() -> {
    if (subscribed.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        return source.doOnUnsubscribe(() -> subscribed.set(false));
    } else {
        return Observable.never();
    }
});

//Let's test it!

TestSubscriber<Integer> ts = TestSubscriber.create(0);
o.subscribe(ts);
ts.requestMore(1);
ts.assertValue(1);
ts.assertNoTerminalEvent();

TestSubscriber<Integer> ts2 = TestSubscriber.create();
o.subscribe(ts2);
ts2.assertNoValues();
ts2.assertNoTerminalEvent();
ts.requestMore(1);
ts.assertValues(1, 2);
ts.assertNoTerminalEvent();

ts.unsubscribe();
TestSubscriber<Integer> ts3 = TestSubscriber.create();
o.subscribe(ts3);
ts3.assertValues(1, 2, 3);
ts3.assertCompleted();
```